# Elsevier cas-sc template unable to center the caption for figure and Table

Tags: tables, els-cas

I am writing a paper for Elsevier using `cas-sc.cls`. The captions for both figure and table are ragged to right. even the following command didn't work with me

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=centering, singlelinecheck=on]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=centering,singlelinecheck=on}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make up a complete compilable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The following MWE gives a justified caption instead of ragged right: Output I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vldBm.png

Comment: `\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae }
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to change the default design of a journal's template?

Comment: Thank you leandris for kind response.\documentclass{cas-sc} \usepackage{natbib} \begin{document} \begin{figure} \caption{Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum}\end{figure} \end{document}. ------------------- my figure caption is single line and short. please tell me how to center the caption in this case with cas-cs document class